# Не происходит запись в БД

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, mysqli

Есть кнопки категорий, которые выводятся циклом **foreach** и соответственно таких кнопок несколько:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<button name="addArticle" class="btn_buy" type="button" onclick="addToCart(<?=$key['id']?>)">Купить</button>
</form>
```

```
function addToCart(id){
 $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'../cart/cart.php',
      data:{add_id:id},
      success:function(data){
           $("#students").html(data);
      }
 });
}
```

```
<?
$idGoods = $_POST['add_id'];
echo $idGoods;
function addGoodsCart($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8) {
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `cart` (`cookie`, `title`, `idMainSect`, `brand`, `img1`, `coin`, `price`, `amount`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ssssssss", $p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
}
if(isset($_POST['addArticle'])){
    addGoodsCart($idGoods, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
}
```

При клике на **button** не происходит запись в БД, но если удалить из PHP блок кода **if(isset($_POST['addArticle'])){}** то запись добавляется, и так же добавляется если просто обновить страницу. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеет функцию, которая делает POST запрос с телом

`{add_id:id}`

(Javascript объект с ключем add_id и значением id)

```
function addToCart(id){
 $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'../cart/cart.php',
      data:{add_id:id},
      success:function(data){
           $("#students").html(data);
      }
 });
}
```

А затем ваш обработчик в части кода на PHP пытается получить данные из тела запроса. Помимо add_id вы хотите получить данные поля **addArticle**, которое вы НЕ передаете с клиента.
Поэтому `isset($_POST['addArticle'])` будет возвращать **false**;
А `isset($_POST['add_id'])` будет возвращать **true** и его можно использовать;

Comment: Мир тебе дружище!